# Is "forenoon" commonly used?

Tags: word-choice, time

I came across this word in some software code written by someone else. I knew what it meant (in Dutch we call it *voormiddag*), but I didn't know the word exists.

I've always heard/seen people refer to *morning* and *afternoon*, never to *forenoon* and *afternoon*. Is it a word people commonly use?

Comment: Forenoon is a very common word used among the Amish and their surrounding communities.

Comment: In dutch none uses "voormiddag" by my knowledge. Moreover "voormiddag" means 12-14 generally (source: http://taaladvies.net/taal/advies/vraag/878/voormiddag_namiddag/) while forenoon probably means some period before 12:00. I guess that the meaning is different.

Comment: @user1043065 I wasn't aware of the difference in meaning between Belgium and the Netherlands, interesting link.

Comment: No. I didn't even know that word existed, and I'm a native speaker who prides myself on vocabulary.

Comment: No it is not common. I've never said the word in my life. However, I will not advise you to not use it. If you use it, maybe you can teach a native speaker a new word and there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Morning* is a common English word, as you know.  *Forenoon*, on the other hand, is so rare that I'm not sure many native speakers of English will even **recognize** the word.

How rare is it?  To find out, I searched [*the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)*](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=33239565) for both *morning* and *forenoon*.  Here are the results I got:

```
　
　　Search term             Number of results
　　-------------------------------------------
　　morning                 128954
　　forenoon                16
```

That makes *morning* roughly **eight thousand** times more common than *forenoon*.  It's safe to say you should stick to *morning* and avoid *forenoon* entirely.

But wait!  Is it possible *forenoon* is only used in dialects of English other than US English?  To find out, I searched [the Corpus of Global Web-Based English (GloWbE)](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=33239622), which contains samples of English from twenty countries.  And in **none** of those countries was it substantially more common than in the US; the numbers in every country were less than one occurrence per million words.  And the few results that I do find are mostly in fiction.

So yes, it is safe to say: avoid *forenoon*.  Use *morning* instead.

Comment: You robbed my reps. Grrr! Anyway +1 for seeing how much same this answer is with what I was going to post. :-)

Comment: Yes, you are good at getting search result facts, like on my plural of octopus question.

Answer (score 13):

It's not exactly obsolete, but *forenoon* is [at the very least a "dated" usage...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=morning%20or%20afternoon,forenoon%20or%20afternoon&year_start=1810&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

Any native speakers would understand *forenoon*, but most people wouldn't use the term themselves, and they'd probably notice and classify it as a "minor mistake" if they heard a non-native speaker using it.

Comment: Actually, I being a non-native speaker heard the word first time.

Comment: @Mistu4u: But you being relatively competent in English, I don't suppose you'd have any problem *understanding* the word if you first came across it *used in context* (which would most likely be if you were reading text written a century or two ago).

Comment: @Mistu4u: I think it also depends on which literature you read. I mostly read fantasy and the word forenoon appears time to time.

Comment: @MasterPJ, No,no. I absolutely left reading English literature 4 years ago. Now my only resource of using English is speaking with people around here (_where I live_), posting in SE and chatting here. Might be, that's why I never heard of it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers i have never heard of "forenoon" too but it really is clear "(be)fore" - "noon" just like "after" - "noon".

Comment: @Berker: I specifically chose to graph "morning/forenoon or **afternoon**" because the familiar *(be)fore/after* conjunction will make some people choose *forenoon* for that specific sequence, even if they'd more likely use *morning* in most other contexts. Just graphing "morning,forenoon" [isn't very enlightening](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=morning%2Cforenoon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), because it gives you no idea of how usage has changed over the last couple of centuries.

Comment: @FumbleFingers than it's a lucky guess comes in mind..

Answer (score 8):

More broadly than the other answers, **forenoon** is one of the time-of-day terms that has become much less commonly used over the last century or so, possibly as a result of the widespread use of artificial lighting. In earlier times, it was common to see the day divided into much more specific segments, but now only the terms in bold are in common usage for describing the time of day:

- dawn
- twilight (morning)
- *sunrise*
- **morning**
- forenoon
- **midday**
- **afternoon**
- **evening**
- *sunset*
- twilight (evening)
- dusk
- **night**

As a fan of the [Aubrey–Maturin series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubrey%E2%80%93Maturin_series), set in the early 1800s, I'm quite familiar with the nautical term "forenoon watch", but I can't ever recall having seen "forenoon" used in a modern setting.

Comment: All of those are still common words, though, except *forenoon*.  And *forenoon* was, even in its heyday of the mid-1800s, still far less common than *morning*; even at its peak, *morning* was roughly 50 times more common (according to a search in [COHA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/)).

Answer (score 5):

I grew up on a dairy farm in Dover, PA. My family, as with most folks in the region, are influenced by PA Dutch (not Dutch as in from Holland but Dutch Anglicized Deutsch/German) dialects.

I'm not surprised it doesn't show up in Internet searches as I don't know that I've ever actually written the word but have used it commonly among my family and others from the region in conversation regularly.

Answer (score 3):

I am a British, native speaker of English, living in Denmark. I like the word 'forenoon' and sometimes use it, particularly in writing. I do not regard it as archaic, but I may however be influenced in this by Danish, a language I speak every day and fluently. In Danish, we distinguish between 'morgen' (morning) and 'formiddag' (forenoon). We say 'God morgen!' (Good morning!), but only up until about 09.30 or 10.00 hrs. After that, we switch to 'Goddag!' (Good day!).

I have always regarded 'forenoon' as a word much more used and favoured in Scotland than in England, and I admit that it is generally speaking far more used by older people than younger ones. 'Forenoon' has a nice ring to it, I feel. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Forenoon is a common word to represent the timing between 10am  to 12 noon,.I dont think morning is an apt word to represent 11 am. If somebody uses morning, it naturally sounds a time between 6 am to  10  am in my understanding .I dont know weather or not  the native speakers avoided this word by the influence of sms and all..

Comment: I think you're going to have to back up your assertion that "forenoon" is *common*, since I and others here would consider it fairly unusual at best, and quite rare at worst. I'm a fairly literate native speaker, but I didn't even know it meant anything other than exactly the same as "morning". Also, "morning" in AmE is used very nearly as much for 11:55 AM as for 7:30 AM.