# Is it a correct expression ? and How to express it?

Tags: word-usage

1. She has to be shot a tourist attraction video for Japanese tomorrow forenoon, starring her. (not herself, because someone shoots the video starring her.)
2. If I get rid of comma(,) in "video for Japanese, starring her", it comes to mean she is Japanese ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't constructed quite correctly and contains some words/phrases which are not natural.

Even though "shooting" is the correct verb for creating video footage, we tend not to say *people* have been "shot", or are "being shot", because it sounds like they've been shot with a gun. Better to move that verb to make it clear that it is a video shoot.

Rather than say "she is in it" and then repeat "starring her", it makes more sense to state that once at the beginning.

"Forenoon", while it *is* a word, is [not commonly used](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10900/is-forenoon-commonly-used/10932). Better to use the more natural "morning".

> She is *starring* in a Japanese tourist attraction video shooting tomorrow *morning*.

Comment: Or simply: "She has {**to shoot**} a video for **Japanese tourists**, tomorrow {**before noon** (or *morning*).}